# Draggable point in matplotlib - How to retrieve point coordinates

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, coordinates, draggable, pyside

I would like to be able to move a point (matplotlib.patches.Ellipse) along a vertical line. To do so, I'm calling the Dragable rectangle class (http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/event_handling.html) inside a PySide QtGui.QWidget.

The dragging of my ellipse works fine, but I'm stuck in how to retrieve the final y-coordinate of the ellipse when I release the mouse button (I want to have a QLabel next to the plot that contains this y-coordinate). From on_release I have its final position:

```
def on_release(self, event):
    if DraggablePoint.lock is not self:
        return
    self.point.newYcoordinate = self.point.center[1]
    self.press = None
    DraggablePoint.lock = None

    # draw everything but the selected point and store the pixel buffer
    canvas = self.point.figure.canvas
    axes = self.point.axes
    self.point.set_animated(True)
    canvas.draw()
    self.background = canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.point.axes.bbox)

    # now redraw just the point
    axes.draw_artist(self.point)

    # and blit just the redrawn area
    canvas.blit(axes.bbox)
```

but how can I connect this to the text of my QLabel (and obtain that this label is updated each time the ellipse is moved)?

```
self.FlexibleValue = patches.Ellipse(xy=(0.5, 0.5), width=0.2, height=0.2, edgecolor='r', facecolor='r', lw=2)
self.axesResp.add_patch(self.FlexibleValue)
self.dragValue = DraggablePoint(self.FlexibleValue)
self.dragValue.connect()
```

Comment: Emit a signal in your call-back

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell ! Actually this is straightforward, but as I just started using PySide, I'm lacking some basics ;-)

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question.

Comment: tcawell meant that you can actually post an answer to your question, then you can mark it as accepted. Can you please do that?

Comment: Sorry, rephrased my edit as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding a signal as tcaswell suggested:

```
def on_release(self, event):
    ...
    self.signal.updatedSignal.emit(str(self.point.newYcoordinate))
```

and then retrieving the y-coordinate:

```
self.dragValue.signal.updatedSignal.connect(self.updatedValue)
```

with:

```
def updatedValue(self, newValue):
    self.labelValue.setText(newValue)
```

and:

```
class UpdatedSignal(QtCore.QObject):
    updatedSignal = QtCore.Signal(str)
```